# How to access localhost from android?

Tags: android, web-services, http

i tried all the ways (10.2.2. or 127.0.0.1 or my_ip:port, port opening) but i cant access neither with chrome, but on my laptop i can see my localhost from pc. 
my ip: 192.168.1.101
port: 29710

it's loading, loading loading and nothing.

pls someone help me

Comment: Can you access other internet sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the firewall of server then access it and make sure you have on same network and connected to LAN.

To check whether you are connected or not.

```
ping server-ip-address
```

Comment: thx! i dont know what has changed but it works now (with or without firewall)

Comment: of course...but i have to wait 10 min...(from my apk i cant reach he localhost :D)

Comment: can i make a rule that allows this program through the nod firewall?

Comment: @David You can not access unless and until firewall is ON.

Comment: hi i cannot reach my localhost server, but i turned off the firewall